# Crystal Reports runs locally -cant find a table (really a stored proc) when deployed

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, runtime, report

I have some Crystal Reports that have been running on a server fine for years -SQL Server 2005, Windows 2008. We recently upgraded the server to a new machine Win 2019, SQL Server 2014.
Nothing changed in the application - just copied it over to the new setup. Application works great, the reports "kind of" run. What's happening is that the stored procedures in the reports are "not found". The tricky part is that the reports have tables and a stored procedure that are all joined together. I didn't write the reports so I don't know  why it was done this way. The SQL of the report looks like this: (Appears to be 2 data sources in the SQL)

Audit_BSA
{CALL "AUDIT_BSA"."dbo"."sp_Diagnosis_Variance_rpt";1(NULL, NULL, NULL)}
EXTERNAL JOIN sp_Diagnosis_Variance_rpt;1.Clientid={?Audit_BSA: AUDIT.ClientID} AND sp_Diagnosis_Variance_rpt;1.auditid={?Audit_BSA: AUDIT.AuditID}

Audit_BSA
SELECT "CLIENT"."CLIENT_NAME", "AUDIT"."Audit_Period_Desc", "AUDIT"."AuditID", "AUDIT"."ClientID"
FROM   "AUDIT_BSA"."dbo"."AUDIT" "AUDIT" INNER JOIN "AUDIT_BSA"."dbo"."CLIENT" "CLIENT" ON "AUDIT"."ClientID"="CLIENT"."ClientID"
WHERE  "AUDIT"."ClientID"={?Audit_BSA: sp_Diagnosis_Variance_rpt;1.Clientid} AND "AUDIT"."AuditID"={?Audit_BSA: sp_Diagnosis_Variance_rpt;1.auditid}

So it appears that the stored proc returns some data and then Crystal Reports is doing the joining to the other real tables.  The reports return data and appear to be working, with the exception of one. In either case an error pops up complaining that Crystal could not locate the stored procedure, but apparently can see the real tables - but only on the new server. If I run the report on our DEV machine -which is SQL server 2008 - it does not give that message.

The Application in C# replaces the data source on the report with the credentials of the new database -via common code that loops all the tables and assigns the correct info.

Has anyone experienced anything like this ?

UPDATE: This is the code that assigns the DB connection info at runtime:

```
            ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();

            TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
            TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
            ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();


            // Load the report document from the Session object.

            // If it's not there, generate a new report document.
            if (this.PageContext.Parent.Context.Session["CATRpt"] == null)
            //if (Session["CATRpt"] == null)
            {
               
                string is_ReportObjectName = "~/Resources/Reports/" + this.PageContext.Parent.Context.Session["csrrpt"];
                string reportPath = Server.MapPath(is_ReportObjectName);
                rpt.Load(reportPath);

                this.PageContext.Parent.Context.Session["CATRpt"] = rpt;
            }
            else
            {
               rpt = (ReportDocument)this.PageContext.Parent.Context.Session["CATRpt"];
            }

            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;

            rpt.SetDatabaseLogon(MainForm.dbuser, MainForm.dbpwd, MainForm.dbserver, MainForm.dbdb);

            //Set the ConnectionInfo properties for logging on to the Database 


            //If you are using ODBC, this should be the DSN name NOT the physical server name. If 
            //you are NOT using ODBC, this should be the physical server name 

            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = MainForm.dbserver;

            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = MainForm.dbdb;
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = MainForm.dbuser;
            crConnectionInfo.Password = MainForm.dbpwd;

            //This code works for both user tables and stored 
            //procedures. Set the CrTables to the Tables collection 
            //of the report 

            Tables CrTables = rpt.Database.Tables;

            // Assign to all tables used by the report

            //Loop through each table in the report and apply the 
            //LogonInfo information 
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in CrTables)
            {
                crtableLogoninfo = table.LogOnInfo;
                crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                table.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);

                table.Location = crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName + ".dbo." + table.Location.Substring(table.Location.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);

            }
```

UPDATE: We added code to log any errors on the Crystal Object Error event and we get:

Invalid Argument provided.
Failed to retrieve data from the database.
Error in File Primary diagnostic code variance {C2484387-1DD8-46B2-B71E-25C1D6641019}.rpt:
Invalid argument for database.

Again - it works fine on our dev machine - which we also installed SQL Server 2014 to match the server. No error on the Dev machine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For Crystal Reports 13 - does it require a 32 bit ODBC connection or 64 Bit - doing some searches it says that Crystal only supports 32 bit ODBC connections. We have a 64 Bit connection, but some of the reports seem to work with this connection.

Comment: We added a 32 bit ODBC connection and now we get the error:. Logon failed.
Error in File Primary diagnostic code variance {7E99C227-4DAC-497B-AB22-BD2227DF7F19}.rpt:
Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters. So it must be looking for 64 bit ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

So we figured  it out - for anyone else having the issue:
If you install Crystal Reports 64 Bit runtime on your server- use a 64 Bit ODBC connection. Also we had to use the "SQL Server" ODBC Driver and not the "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server" driver.